# Embedding of Sobolev Space $W^{n, \infty}(\Omega)$ into $C^{n-1}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

In a paper I was studying it was used that $W^{n, \infty}([0,1]^d)\subset C^{n-1}([0,1]^d)$. I have searched for hours but I cannot seem to find a reference or proof of that. I suppose that it follows from some Sobolev embedding theorem but they usually only consider the case $p<\infty$.

Can someone help me out and explain why the result is true and/or provide a reference?

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: See the chapter V of the book:  R.Adams, *Sobolev Spaces* (1975)

Comment: Thank you! Could you maybe refine a bit more in which subsection exactly i can find the reference? Because from what I have seen in chapter V, only the case $p<\infty$ was treated in the theorems

Comment: Isn't that follows from standard sobolev embedding? See the wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#General_Sobolev_inequalities)

Comment: I read that as well but I was not really sure if that is actually enough. Can $p=\infty$ there? Then my result follows from the case $k>\frac{n}{p}$, right? But also, there is no reference given for this result

Comment: @PollyNomial Since you're on a bounded domain, you have $W^{n,\infty}$ embeds into $W^{n,p}$ for all $1 < p < \infty.$ This simply follows from the usual inclusion of $L^p$ spaces.